# Need to know how to have my own iCloud account?

Tags: iphone, icloud

If me and my two kids share the same iCloud and I constantly see them sharing my materials. How can I separate without loosing my personal stuff?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is for all of you to have your own iCloud accounts.  As long as you share the same iCloud account with your kids, or anyone, they'll be able to view and edit your documents.

You didn't mention the ages of your kids, but Apple allows you to create iCloud accounts for minors so you can have parental controls over various aspects of their accounts.  FWW, I had the same problem and created accounts for my kids and wife.  Doing that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend, not only separate AppleIDs for each family member, but also [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060)

One account becomes the Family Organiser, any others can be set up as adult or child, with parental controls. Once you've set up Family Sharing, everyone can access each others' apps, music, movies, TV shows and books - yet not each other's data unless explicitly shared, so privacy is retained.